# Blank columns after each filled column in csv

Tags: php, csv, openoffice.org, export-to-csv, openoffice-calc

I am getting blank column after each filled column in openoffice 3.3.
In my PHP code I have provided ~~ as the seperator and \n as the delimiter

I am using this PHP code 
    header("Content-type: application/csv");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="dsds.csv");
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Expires: 0");
echo $filecontent;

How can I get rid of the blank columns

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of an additional empty column would be if you are adding the column delimiter at the end of the row, just before the newline like this:

```
column1value~~column2value~~column3value~~\n
```

instead of correctly ommitting the final delimiter, like this:

```
column1value~~column2value~~column3value\n
```

If there is a gap after every column, the most likely cause is that open office is only registering the first character in your delimiter. For maximum compatibility, I would recommend using a comma as your delimiter and text delimiting your fields with double quotes to avoid breaking around commas that may appear in your data:

```
"column1value","column2value","a value, containing a comma"\n
```

If you are concerned about having double quotes in your data too, then I would further recommend escaping those quotes by using another double quote:

```
"column1value","column2value","a value containing ""double quotes"""\n
```

See the CSV specification for more information: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

Comment: I am removing the ~~ from the end before placing a newline , and it is just not one column that come blank , after each filled column there is a blank one like A is filled B is empty , C is filled D is empty ...  so a single row has a blank column to the right of a value column

Comment: Try using a single character as your delimiter (i.e. `~` instead of `~~`)

Comment: the single ~ can come in my data